# Fetch Pre-Selected Results

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a complex SQL statement that takes a long time to execute. This is going to be a problem as more users start using the system simultaneously.

Are there any options for sorting results in advance and then assigning them to Java POJO's using Hibernate? This way the processed information is already sitting in the MySQL DB waiting for retrieval without doing it upon execute...

I've looked into **DB Views** + **Hibernate** but didn't find much...

Comment: You should first try to optimize the query in the database, before attempting caching at either the application or database level.

Comment: Take a look ak this. [parallel processing](http://searchitchannel.techtarget.com/feature/Parallel-processing-Using-parallel-SQL-effectively)[link]

Comment: Your possible solution is used in situations where such logic is necessary.  It adds additional layers of maintenance and consistency, but is sometimes necessary.  It just isn't the first approach to boosting performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look at indexing. I dont think that ist possible prefetch results of sql queries. If query cannot be optimized and it is really REALLY important then you can maybe use some parallel implementation for processing query.